# How to dissolve two lines only when there is a point between them?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, spatial-join

I have a network of line features. Each lines are supposed to be connected to other line end to end at nodes. The connected lines (at nodes) may or may not have different IDs (yes there can be two lines with same ID in the same featuere). I want to make a join based on the attribute IDs available on each line. That is, I want join to happen between end to end touching lines only if there is no point (which is from a different point feature class) between them. The red pentagons on the attached figure shows those locations.

[image]

How did I get here? The black dots and the pink squares are the only points where I wanted the lines to be split on the first place. First, I used join to join to join all these line features and then used split lines at points to split them only at the points. Strangely, the line also splits at the red pentagons shows (apparently, intersection between two lines).

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you add images to your question..

Comment: How many point/line features are there?

Comment: @ianbroad there are about 1000 point and 1700 line features

Comment: when you run the dissolve tool, are you UNchecking the 'create multipart features'?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Advanced license, you can do this in 2 steps

1. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) lines with the ID field as `Dissolve Field(s)` parameter
2. [Split Line at Point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm) to cut the lines when there is a point intersecting them.

Comment: I tried this before. But there is a problem, it also splits the line at intersection between two lines or if the line is intersecting itself (i.e also at locations where there is no point features).

Comment: see image attached, this problem was created by using dissolve and split line at point at the first place

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a manual process, here is a workflow:

1. Select by location where your lines intersect your points.
2. Switch the selection:

[image]

3. Run the dissolve tool on the lines and dissolve using the ID field (it will only run on the selected features, which are the lines that DO NOT intersect any points).

Comment: but, I want the lines dissolve if there IS a point in between.

Comment: the wording of your question is very confusing.

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in ArcMap you should be able to do this with a dissolve on the ID.

Comment: using dissolve, i can dissolve the lines with similar IDs. I don't want two lines to be dissolved if there is a point between them.

Comment: @user3548453 I think I understand now. You have segmented lines like so: ----- You want these to be one feature. If you run into this: -----|----- You want three separate features. If so I think I have the solution.

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: So the pentagons are areas that represent overpasses, underpasses, and in some cases a continuation of the same line (street?). The line ends at the pentagon have two sets of IDs, so the east west lines in the pentagon in bottom center have the same line end IDs and the north -south have the same IDS that are different from the east west IDs?